# Creating package with customized component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create a Material UI component and provide that as a single component in npm private repository in my company.

I customize Date picker (I created Date range picker, Materials UI doesn't support that, thanks for [that](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/364#issuecomment-571813927)) and it has some custom class styles. When I import/export components inside the project its getting values from my theme, but when I import bundled component from npm package I think that imported component use uses his syles inside.

CODE: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mendel-2b1em

**Now, question**

How can I create a reusable component in these cases with provides global (project) theme? I didn't found "good practices" in MUI Docs.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I should respond to that issue.

I added externals in my webpack file.

For example:

```
...
  externals: [
    {
      react: {
        root: "React",
        commonjs2: "react",
        commonjs: "react",
        amd: "react",
      },
      "react-dom": {
        root: "ReactDOM",
        commonjs2: "react-dom",
        commonjs: "react-dom",
        amd: "react-dom",
      },
    },
    "lodash",
    "@material-ui/core",
    /@material-ui\/core\/*./,
    "@material-ui/pickers",
    /@material-ui\/pickers\/*./,
    "@material-ui/styles",
    /@material-ui\/styles\/*./,
  ],
...
```

It excludes libraries from my package bundle and package after install begins to use the libraries from a project and the theme started works fine!